# Why is "be" used instead of "is" in this sentence "Be he alive, or be he dead"?

Tags: word-choice, subjunctives, literature

> He was a big one, to be sure. At his belt he had three calves strung up by the heels, and he unhooked them and threw them down on the table and said: 'Here, wife, broil me a couple of these for breakfast. Ah! what's this I smell?
>
> 'Fee-fi-fo-fum,
>   I smell the blood of an Englishman,
>   **Be he alive, or be he dead**,
>   I'll have his bones to grind my bread.'

This content is from "Jack and the Beanstalk"

Why is "be" used instead of "is" in this sentence "Be he alive, or be he dead"?

Comment: This is a very good question.

Comment: **Be** makes it declarative statement. **Is** makes it a question. It is essentially saying "If he is alive", rather than "Is he alive?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the main thing is that the guilty parties be tracked down -- the subjunctive mood](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51942/the-main-thing-is-that-the-guilty-parties-be-tracked-down-the-subjunctive-moo)

Comment: I have rolled this question back to its original question. Yuuichi you cannot edit your question to ask a different question after your first question has been answered. *Make a new post with a new question, instead*

Comment: Yes, the change of the question may confuse answers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because the sentence is using the **[subjunctive mood](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/)**, which is used to describe hypothetical or unreal situations.  The giant is essentially saying

> whether the Englishman be alive, or whether he be dead

The subjunctive is a very tricky aspect of aspect of English, and [some people argue that it doesn't really exist at all!](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/02/does-english-have-subjunctive/)  You don't see it very much in modern English; it mostly appears in forms like

> It is important that he see a doctor.

where it isn't very obvious, because the subjunctive "see" just looks the same as the bare infinitive anyway.  But when we use the verb "to be", you can see it:

> It is important that he **be* here on time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I rarely came across "Subject + be" like "he be". Is this omitted an auxiliary verb like "would"? And when can I use this?

Comment: No, there's no auxiliary verb omitted.  This is just the way the subjunctive works in clauses like that.  [This page gives a good summary of when to use it.](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html)  What makes the usage in "Jack and the Beanstalk" especially confusing is the way it *begins* with "Be he alive...", but we do use the subjunctive that way for hypotheticals or conditionals. A common, idiomatic use of it is the phrase **"Be that as it may..."** which essentially means "Whether or not that is the way that is..."

Answer (score 0):

The giant is making a statement about the conditional

> Be he alive, or be he dead
>   *whether he (be/is) alive, or whether he (be/is) dead*

Using **is** turns it into a question

> *Is* he alive, or *is* he dead *(?)*

which has a different meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the difference between "is" and "be" in this sentence "whether he (be/is) alive, or whether he (be/is) dead"?

Comment: The "be" form is in the subjunctive, as mentioned in stangdon's answer above. Grammatical purists claim the subjunctive is still the only correct form in certain contexts, but it sounds very old fashioned. "Jack and the Beanstalk" is a very old tale, so an archaic style feels appropriate.

Comment: Can I say like "whether he would be alive, or whether he would be dead"?

Comment: It sounds very formal and a bit verbose but has the same meaning as "whether he is alive, or whether he is dead".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's used here as a subjunctive (occurs pretty rarely). So it sounds to me like:
"Whether he is alive or not (dead), ..."